# Dimension of a subspace $W$ of $M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $M \in M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C})$ and $W$ be a subspace of $M_{4\times 4}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $W$=$L({M^n: n\geq 0})$ .What will be the possibilities for the dimension of $W$ ?

**Attempt:**

I found $W$=$L(I,M,M^2,M^3,M^4,...,M^n,...)$ and $L(I,M,M^2,M^3,M^4,...,M^n,...)$ is not linearly independent set as matrices  $M^5 ,M^6,...$ can be written as a linear combination of $I,M,M^2,M^3,M^4$. So dimension of $W$ will be $\leq 4$ .

Case-$1$ >
$\operatorname{dim}W=4$ ,when $M_{4\times4}$ is not nilpotent matrix .

Case-$2$>
$\operatorname{dim}W=3$ ,when $M_{4\times4}$ is nilpotent matrix of index $4$ .

Case-$3$>
$\operatorname{dim}W=2$ ,when $M_{4\times4}$ is nilpotent matrix of index $3$ .

Case-$4$>
$\operatorname{dim}W=1$ ,when $M_{4\times4}$ is nilpotent matrix of index $2$ .

Case-$5$>
$\operatorname{dim}W=0$ ,when $M_{4\times4}$ is null matrix .

**Question:**

Is my method correct? or something which is missed ?

**Edits:**

$(1)$

here, $L$ represents the linear span set.

$(2)$

Case-$5$ will not exist so,
$\operatorname{dim}W\neq 0$ .

Comment: As you have $M^n$ with $n\ge0$, you'll always have at least the identity matrix.

Comment: $M^0=I$, even for the zero matrix.

Comment: No, always $\dim W\ge1$.

Comment: $L(I)$ is spanned by $I$ and has only $0I=0$ so it is a basis with one vector, $I$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is correct, except that the subspace always contains $I$ as per the statement of the problem, so the dimension cannot be $0$. It can be $1,2,3,4$ as you have shown.

It is, however, possibly much easier to see it on diagonal matrices, because, for $p\in\mathbb C[x]$ and $D=\begin{bmatrix}d_1&0&0&\cdots&0\\0&d_2&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&d_3&\cdots&0\\\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&d_n\end{bmatrix}$, we have $p(D)=\begin{bmatrix}p(d_1)&0&0&\cdots&0\\0&p(d_2)&0&\cdots&0\\0&0&p(d_3)&\cdots&0\\\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots&\cdots\\0&0&0&\cdots&p(d_n)\end{bmatrix}$, so the minimal polynomial of $D$ looks like this: $\mu_D(\lambda)=\prod_{i\in I}(\lambda-d_i)$ where $I$ is the set of indices that gives you all the mutually different $d_i$'s.

Now the subspace you are talking about here is of dimension $\deg\mu_D$, so you can easily find matrices with minimal polynomial of degree $1,2,3,4$, for example: $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ (all diagonal components the same), $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$ (two different components), $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&3\end{bmatrix}$ (three different) and $\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\0&0&3&0\\0&0&0&4\end{bmatrix}$ (all four different).

Comment: how have you got diagonal matrices?

Comment: I have just written them down so that they have between $1$ and $4$ different elements on the diagonal. I could've chosen different matrices, as long as the number of different elements matches. For example, $D=\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0&0\\0&5&0&0\\0&0&3&0\\0&0&0&5\end{bmatrix}$ has $\mu_D(\lambda)=(\lambda-3)(\lambda-5)$, so $D^2=8D-15I$ and the only linearly independent matrices are $I, D$.

Comment: is the case$5$ correct?

Comment: @Abishek Nope, for the same reason mentioned by LordSharktheUnknown: $I$ is always in $W$ so $W$ cannot be of dimension $0$. I've updated my answer to reflect that.